# Get result from http get request Angular7

Tags: javascript, http, httpclient, angular7

Totally lost my mind. I'm confused. My goal is to get reply from my backend server. Here how it works: GET http://localhost:12345/createUser.php?name=John&age=40 returns me this json:

```
{
    "id":"91",
    "name":"John",
    "age":40,
    "birthday":"null"
}
```

I'd like to send this get request via angular and show reply to the page. I ONLY need id and name. So, I create model:

```
export class User {
    id:string;
    name:string;
}
```

And trying to get reply. Here's my two tryes:
1. Just code inside app.component.ts:

```
export class AppComponent implements onInit{ 
  user:User; 

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

  createUser(){
    this.user = this.http.get("http://localhost:12345/createUser.php?name=test&age=20"); 
  }
}
```

and create button and text-div in app.component.html to display it:

```
<button (click)="createUser()">Create test user!</button> 
<div ><h2>{{user.id}} {{user.name}} </h2></div>
```

Aaand.. no result here. But, if I code html like "{{user | json}}", then I get some reply, but it's just request info like this:

```
{ "_isScalar": false, "source": { "_isScalar": false, "source": { "_isScalar": false, "source": { "_isScalar": true, "value": { "url": "http://localhost:12345/createUser.php?name=John&age=40", "body": null, "reportProgress": false, "withCredentials": false, "responseType": "json", "method": "GET", "headers": { "normalizedNames": {}, "lazyUpdate": null, "headers": {} }, "params": { "updates": null, "cloneFrom": null, "encoder": {}, "map": null }, "urlWithParams": "http://localhost:12345/createUser.php?name=John&age=40" } }, "operator": { "concurrent": 1 } }, "operator": {} }, "operator": {} }
```

2. Second try is to create data service. So this is my service:

```
export class DataService {

  apiUrl="http://localhost:12345/createUser.php?name=John&age=40";
  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

  public createUser()
  {
    return this.http.get<User>(this.apiUrl);
  }
}
```

and app.component:

```
user:User;
ngOnInit()
  {
    return this.dataService.createUser().subscribe(data=>this.user=data); 
  }
```

No success. But user is created at my server on both ways. I see that I don't understand some basics, but can't find any good explanation on web. Could you please help me?

Comment: `return this.dataService.createUser().subscribe(data=>this.user=data); ` whe this subscribe call is called did you try to log it on console. Does it really contains the required data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of make sure your api/service is working as expected, i mean its actually returning the required response as you have stated above. Also here is a sample code i have created

```
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient){}
  name = 'Angular';
  data: Data;
  getData(){
    return this.httpClient.get<Data>(`https://swapi.co/api/people/1/`);
  }
  ngOnInit(){
    this.getData().subscribe((res: Data)=>{this.data = res;})
  }

export interface Data{
  name: string;
  height: string;
}

<p>
  Name : {{data.name}} <br>
  Height: {{data.height}}
</p>
```

You see this piece of code working here [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lsbu6j). 
Hope this helps :). Let me know if you still face issues.

Comment: Ok, it seems my server replys in the wrong way. I don't know why huh. My server's response body exactly same as from swapi.co. Could it be because of wrong headers? I could open my server for the world so you could inspect my response.

Comment: If you can give me a endpoint may yes i will be able to help you.. Also if you can edit the Stackblitz demo according to your code.. will help me debug

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I saw the code but your endpoint doesn't seems to work. The issue seems to be with you endpoint and not the angular code. So have a look at you api you can test it with postman on your local machine and when you get the required response the angular code will work fine